# Trigger() or Change() or Click() Question to target those button that have specific value you want

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on what I see from people on StackOverflow, it seems that those functions only target specific elements with specific Id or Class such as a button with an ID of first to trigger a button with an ID of second without actually touch the second button. But I am looking for one that does the same thing but by Val rather than id or class as I have multiple buttons with the same class but have their own value. Here a piece of my code

```
$('<center class=\'centers\'><button class=\'command_button buttons\' value=\'Intro2/2\'>Next</button></center>').appendTo('#choicebox');
```

This is the button that triggers the event, it has a class of buttons but the value of Intro2/2

```
$(document).on('click', '.buttons', function() {

    var button = $(this).val();
    console.log('The Button is ' + button);
    CL();
    $('#container').scrollTop($('#container')[0].scrollHeight);

    switch (button) {

      // Go from Introduction 1/2 to Introduction 2/2.
    case 'Intro2/2': {

      clean();
      
      CCEvents('Intro2/2');

    } break;
```

As you can see there is a .on function that looks for the click event of any element have a class of .buttons,
once found, it will take in that value of button and add it to the variable of a button, then use that variable to find one in switch/cases and match it to Intro2/2 which will trigger the event function that I want which is CCEvents('Intro2/2').

All this is already done, but I am trying to add it to my map system, but need some way to trigger the button without actually click on the button or just direct trigger the CCEvents('Intro2/2')

This is my attempt to use the trigger and click, perhaps I didn't understand how it works and that why it is not working when it is doable with those functions.

```
$("<button class=\'command_button buttons\' value=\'Intro2/2\'>Next</button>").trigger("click");

$(".buttons").val("Intro2/2").change();

$('.buttons').trigger('Intro2/2');

$(".buttons").val("Intro2/2").click();

$(".buttons").trigger("click", "Intro2/2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) like `$('.buttons[value="Intro2/2"]').click()`

```js
$('<center class=\'centers\'><button class=\'command_button buttons\' value=\'Intro2/2\'>Next</button></center>').appendTo('#choicebox');

$(document).on('click', '.buttons', function() {
  var button = $(this).val();
  console.log('The Button is ' + button);
})


$('.buttons[value="Intro2/2"]').click()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="choicebox"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, I can see it work here but not at my side, but I am currently facepalm because I just now notice that event I am trying to trigger already have a function with it, so I just use that function as a trigger. But still, need to figure out how this work because not all of my events are tied with function, and still need to simulate button click with the correct button and its value to get the event I am seeking.

That function is CCEvents("Intro2/2")...

Yeah it was annoying to not see that in first try.